# How to conclude for maximum and minimum values of n according to the given constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

In a 128 days time, each of 9 friends goes to gym on exactly 78 days. There are $n$ days on which at least 5 of the friends gym.
Maximum and minimum possible value of n is ?

> What i did was consider a set of $128$ elements each corresponding to  one student which tells if he goes on {$day_{1},...day_{128}$} or not . Now we can choose pair of 5 students in $\binom{x}{5}$ ways where x is the number of students and we need this to be each pair goes to gym on n days so $n* \binom{x}{5}$ days but how to relate this with 78days so as to conclude for maximum and minimum values of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let binary decision variable $x_{f,d}$ indicate whether friend $f$ goes to the gym on day $d$.
Let binary decision variable $y_d$ indicate whether at least five friends go to the gym on day $d$.  The problem is to maximize or minimize $\sum_d y_d$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_d x_{f,d} &= 78 && \text{for all $f$} \tag1 \\
5 y_d \le \sum_f x_{f,d} &\le 4 + 5 y_d &&\text{for all $d$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces the rule that each friend goes to the gym on exactly $78$ days.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_d = 1 \iff \sum_f x_{f,d} \ge 5$.

Summing $(2)$ over all $d$ yields
$$5 \sum_d y_d \le \sum_d \sum_f x_{f,d} \le 128 \cdot 4 + 5 \sum_d y_d.$$
Applying $(1)$ now yields
$$5 \sum_d y_d \le 9\cdot 78 \le 128 \cdot 4 + 5 \sum_d y_d,$$
from which we deduce bounds
$$38 = \frac{9\cdot 78 - 128 \cdot 4}{5} \le \sum_d y_d \le \frac{9\cdot 78}{5} = 140.4.$$
The upper bound is redundant because we already know that $\sum_d y_d \le 128$.

It turns out that both $38$ and $128$ are attainable.

Comment: Wonderful , how you think of defining such variables which will give 1,0 value for each , i mean can it be done in similar way like which i assumed like assigning a set of 128 elements to each friend telling whther he/she is going on day i or not ?

Comment: I solve optimization problems with binary variables every day, so for me this was the most natural approach.

Answer (score 1):

This in essence is the same as Robs answer.

Total person days available = $9.78 = 702$.

To get maximum, let us evenly spread on $128$ days, we get $\frac{702}{128} > 5$. So $128$ is feasible.

To get smallest, first let us make sure that we have at least $4$ on any day.

This would give us person days as $702 - 4.128 = 190$.

Now let us spread this among only $5$ people. We will get $38$ as minimum. Why only $5$? so we get minimum overlap possible.

Comment: But 190/10 is also integer which gives 19 days so overall we can have 19 days with atleast 10 people going in those days so cannot the minimum be 19 as atleast 10 people already means 5 people are there?

Comment: And what does **person days** term means ?

Comment: For your first comment, we have only 9 friends. Person days is just that, product of persons and days.

Comment: Understood thanks